# Process mining data visualization in Python

Tags: python, graph, visualization, process-management, process-mining

How can I reproduce a visualization like this in Python with the given example dataset? Which module can I use?

```
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| Case_ID |    Timestamp_from     |     Timestamp_to      |             Activity             |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| Case 1  | 7/11/2022 9:22:23 AM  | 7/11/2022 11:24:15 AM | Create Purchase requisition Item |
| Case 1  | 7/11/2022 11:24:15 AM | 7/11/2022 11:28:55 AM | Create Purchase Order Item       |
| Case 1  | 7/11/2022 11:28:55 AM | 7/25/2022 9:41:28 AM  | Send Purchase Order              |
| Case 1  | 7/25/2022 9:41:28 AM  | 7/25/2022 10:15:10 AM | Changed Price                    |
| Case 1  | 7/25/2022 10:15:10 AM |                       | Send Purchase Order              |
| Case 2  | 8/1/2022 4:04:13 PM   | 8/1/2022 6:55:11 PM   | Create Purchase requisition Item |
| Case 2  | 8/1/2022 6:55:11 PM   | 8/1/2022 7:05:39 PM   | Create Purchase Order Item       |
| Case 2  | 8/1/2022 7:05:39 PM   | 8/1/2022 8:49:35 PM   | Record Goods Receipt             |
| Case 2  | 8/1/2022 8:49:35 PM   | 8/5/2022 6:52:19 PM   | Record Invoice Receipt           |
| Case 2  | 8/5/2022 6:52:19 PM   |                       | Invoice Paied                    |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
```

[image: Process mining visualization]

Looking over Google I found many Python libraries to create data visualizations, but nothing related to the mapping of process mining activities.
Any suggestion?